# Ionic 2/ Anuglar 2 how to move parent functions into extended classes

Tags: class, angular, typescript, ionic2, extend

My parent component is too large to manage so I want to move the the functions into the separated child classes that extend the parent.

The parent class contains variables that need to be updated in the child classes as well as I have injected providers into the parent as well.

```
    @Component({
    selector: 'events-list',
    templateUrl: 'events-list.html'

})
export class EventsListComponent {
    filterString: string;
    infiniteScroll: any;
    refresher: any;
    eventsList: any[];
    selectedCategoriesList: [Category];
    pageNum: number;
    pageSize: number;
    searchText: string = '';
    noEvents: boolean;
    filterSearchText: string;
    filterStartDate: string;
    filterEndDate: string;
    tabsFilterValue: string = 'all'

    constructor(

        public authSrvc: AuthSrvc,
        public calendarSrvc: CalendarSrvc,
        public eventsSrvc: EventsSrvc,
        public helperSrvc: HelperSrvc,
        public locationSrvc: LocationSrvc,
        public pushSrvc: PushSrvc) {

    }
```

> Above is my parent class

```
    import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Response} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/timeout';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {ModalController, LoadingController, NavController, ToastController, Platform} from 'ionic-angular';
import {Storage} from '@ionic/storage';
import {DateFormatPipe} from 'angular2-moment';
import {Category} from '../../../app/app.interfaces';
import * as moment from 'moment';

/** Ionic Native **/
import {GoogleAnalytics} from '@ionic-native/google-analytics';
import {Network} from '@ionic-native/network';

/** Providers **/
import {AuthSrvc} from '../../../../providers/auth-srvc';
import {CalendarSrvc} from '../../../../providers/calendar-srvc';
import {EventsSrvc} from '../../../../providers/events-srvc';
import {HelperSrvc} from '../../../../providers/helper-srvc';
import {LocationSrvc} from '../../../../providers/location-srvc';
import {PushSrvc} from '../../../../providers/push-srvc';

/** Pages **/
import {AuthPage} from '../../../pages/auth/auth-page';

import {EventsListComponent} from '../../../events-components/events-list/events-list';

export class eventsInit extends EventsListComponent {

    constructor(
        loadingCtrl: LoadingController,
        toastCtrl: ToastController,
        modalCtrl: ModalController,
        navCtrl: NavController,
        platform: Platform,
        storage: Storage,

        ga: GoogleAnalytics,
        network: Network,

        authSrvc: AuthSrvc,
        calendarSrvc: CalendarSrvc,
        eventsSrvc: EventsSrvc,
        helperSrvc: HelperSrvc,
        locationSrvc: LocationSrvc,
        pushSrvc: PushSrvc

    ) {
        super(loadingCtrl,
        toastCtrl,
        modalCtrl,
        navCtrl,
        platform,
        storage,

        ga,
        network,

        authSrvc,
        calendarSrvc,
        eventsSrvc,
        helperSrvc,
        locationSrvc,
        pushSrvc);
    }

    ngOnInit()
    {
        console.log('test')
    }
}
```

> Above is my child class

this is not working and is always failing with by parameters not being populated or the super call failing. What is the correct way to do this.

/** Update **/

If removing the injectable I always get the error Can't resolve all parameters for eventsInit: (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?).

> Below is my main module

```
    import {NgModule, ErrorHandler} from '@angular/core';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {Ng2ImgFallbackModule} from 'ng2-img-fallback';
import {CloudSettings, CloudModule} from '@ionic/cloud-angular';
import {MomentModule,DateFormatPipe} from 'angular2-moment';
import { IonicStorageModule } from '@ionic/storage';

import {IonicApp, IonicModule, IonicErrorHandler} from 'ionic-angular';
import {EnvironmentsModule} from '../environment_variables/environment_variables.module'
import {AppConfig} from '../app/app.config';
import {MyApp} from '../app/app.component';

/** Ionic Native **/
import {Calendar} from '@ionic-native/calendar';
import { Diagnostic } from '@ionic-native/diagnostic';
import {Facebook} from '@ionic-native/facebook';
import {GooglePlus} from '@ionic-native/google-plus';
import { GoogleAnalytics } from '@ionic-native/google-analytics';
import { Keyboard } from '@ionic-native/keyboard';
import { LaunchNavigator, LaunchNavigatorOptions } from '@ionic-native/launch-navigator';
import {Network} from '@ionic-native/network';
import { SocialSharing } from '@ionic-native/social-sharing';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';

/** Pages **/
import {AuthPage} from '../pages/auth/auth-page';
import {EventsPage} from '../pages/events/events-page';
import {EventPage} from '../pages/event/event-page';
import {ProfilePage} from '../pages/profile/profile';
import {SettingsPage} from '../pages/settings/settings';

/** Components **/
//Auth
import {LoginComponent} from '../components/auth-components/login/login';
import {ForgotPasswordDirective} from '../components/auth-components/forgot-password';
import {RegisterComponent} from '../components/auth-components/register/register';
import {SocialComponent} from '../components/auth-components/social/social';
import {WalkthroughComponent} from '../components/auth-components/walkthrough/walkthrough';
//Base
import {SidenavComponent} from '../components/sidenav/sidenav';
import {TimeslotFilterComponent} from '../components/timeslot-filter/timeslot-filter';
import {SettingsComponent} from '../components/settings/settings';
import {EventBookComponent} from '../components/event-book/event-book';
//Events
import {EventsFilterComponent} from '../components/events-components/events-filter/events-filter';
import {EventsListComponent} from '../components/events-components/events-list/events-list';
    /** Events Extensions **/
    import {eventsInit} from '../components/events-components/events-list/extensions/events-init';
import {EventsItemComponent} from '../components/events-components/events-item/events-item';
//Event
import {AttendeesListComponent} from '../components/event-components/attendees-list/attendees-list';
import {AttendeesItemComponent} from '../components/event-components/attendees-item/attendees-item';
//Profile
import {ProfileComponent} from '../components/profile/profile';

import {ParallaxHeaderDirective} from '../components/parallax-header';

/** Providers **/
import {EventsSrvc} from '../providers/events-srvc';
import {AuthSrvc} from '../providers/auth-srvc';
import {CalendarSrvc} from '../providers/calendar-srvc';
import {HelperSrvc} from '../providers/helper-srvc';
import {LocationSrvc} from '../providers/location-srvc';
import {PushSrvc} from '../providers/push-srvc';

/** Pipes **/
import {LimitToPipe} from '../pipes/limitTo'

const cloudSettings: CloudSettings = {
    'core': {
        'app_id': 'df0d4e63'
    }
};

class NetworkMock extends Network { 
 get type(): string {
    return (super['type'] === null) ? "wifi" : super['type'];
  }
}

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        MyApp,
        AuthPage,
        LoginComponent,
        ForgotPasswordDirective,
        ParallaxHeaderDirective,
        RegisterComponent,
        SocialComponent,
        WalkthroughComponent,
        SidenavComponent,
        EventsPage,
        EventsListComponent,
        eventsInit,
        EventsItemComponent,
        EventsFilterComponent,
        AttendeesListComponent,
        AttendeesItemComponent,
        EventPage,
        ProfilePage,
        ProfileComponent,
        SettingsPage,
        SettingsComponent,
        TimeslotFilterComponent,
        EventBookComponent,
        LimitToPipe,
    ],
    imports: [
        IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp,
            {
                backButtonText: 'Back',
                backButtonIcon: 'arrow-back',
                iconMode: 'md',
                modalEnter: 'modal-slide-in',
                modalLeave: 'modal-slide-out',
                tabsPlacement: 'bottom',
                pageTransition: 'md',
                mode: 'md'
            }),
            IonicStorageModule.forRoot(),
        CloudModule.forRoot(cloudSettings),
        FormsModule,
        MomentModule,
        EnvironmentsModule,
        Ng2ImgFallbackModule
    ],
    bootstrap: [IonicApp],
    entryComponents: [
        MyApp,
        AuthPage,
        EventsPage,
        EventPage,
        ProfilePage,
        SettingsPage,
        EventBookComponent,
        EventsFilterComponent,
        SidenavComponent
    ],
    providers: [{provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
    Calendar,
    Diagnostic,
    Facebook,
    GooglePlus,
    DateFormatPipe,
    GoogleAnalytics,
    Keyboard,
    LaunchNavigator,
    { provide: Network, useClass: NetworkMock },
    SocialSharing,
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen, 
    EventsSrvc,
    AuthSrvc,
    CalendarSrvc,
    HelperSrvc,
    EventsSrvc, 
    LocationSrvc,
    AppConfig]
})
export class AppModule {

}
```

Comment: Have you found the solution?

Comment: I went with attribute based directives and it was right. BUT your answer is correct so I will mark it that way.

Comment: Hmm.. good to know about that.But hope you'll share your solution too? Hope we can learn something new from you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to follow below mentioned implementation.I have implemented this in my app and it is working fine.

**Note:** This is just a structure.Please implement it as you wish.

*your component class:*

```
import { eventsInit } from "../../path-for-it";

    export class EventsListComponent extends eventsInit {

      constructor() {
        super();

      }
```

*Base class:*

```
 export abstract class eventsInit {


      protected YourMethodName(res: Response) {

      }


    }
```

**Update:**

It seems you have not followed the latest changes of `provider` implementation.You have to declare it inside the `app.module.ts` file.Please see this article: [**Providers**](https://x-team.com/blog/using-remote-web-services-ionic-2-mobile-app/)

Comment: I tried this as well and I get told I am not passing all the required parameters for the super to be used (Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.). And if I dont use the super the constructor fails.

Comment: why you cannot use `super()`? You have to pass all the required parameters for the `base class` through `super()`.Why can't you do that?

Comment: I have tried that as well which shows in my code above but then its tells me.

Can't resolve all parameters for eventsInit: (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?).

Comment: your component class must be a subclass here.But you have done it other way around.That is why that error.

Comment: Why/How can the parent be a subclass as the template and the main variables are defined in it?

Comment: when we use `abstract` class normally we say it as a base class no? class naming is not the problem here.I have a working app using my method.

Comment: Can you show me a more advanced snipper based on what i have done so I can see the correct implementation? your current example is very basic and does not take into account parameters and providers being used.

Comment: one question: why you have used this `providers: [AuthSrvc, CalendarSrvc, DateFormatPipe, EventsSrvc,` on your component? it should be under the `app.module.ts` no? are you using RCx version yet or?

Comment: In ionic they say I need to include them but if there is a better way then by all means please give me a link.

Comment: are you using `"ionic-angular": "2.2.0",` or ?

Comment: 2.2.0 as 2.3.0 has a virtual scroll bug in it. =(

Comment: I moved it all into the module and its still the same error.

Comment: can you show your final code? put that under a different section on your question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139231/discussion-between-ross-rawlins-and-sampath).

Answer (score 0):

So after banging the extend class logic into my head and understanding that it wasnt the correct way to break up my code. I went with an attribute based directives with @Hostlistener and @Input variables.

I was able to break up the parent component into much smaller sections and allow the parent component to hold all the variables and pass the updated values to the directives. I went from 1 component over 500 lines to multiple that dont go over 120. Much easier to read, to test and to maintain.